# Dropbox Api putFile php fail send file

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am trying send a file to Dropbox using http://www.dropbox-php.com/

Dropbox-PHP answers: `Forbidden. This could mean a bad OAuth request, or a file or folder already existing at the target location.`

I have send a request, just for the test, where I try get account info. Success. I get information about my account.

Next I try get metadata about file which I'll send. `No such file.`

Metadata other files I get.

What is causing the problem?

Comment: Could you paste the code? It will be a lot easier to help you if we could see your code :-)

Comment: @Cupcake, thank you, but problem solved. 10 minutes after a question files start puts to dropbox. I don't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the requested **path**. Try to remove slash '**/**' from the beginning of **path**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API you are using is broken.

Here is a simple Dropbox-PHP example:

https://github.com/hawaiianchimp/Dropbox-PHP-API